# PayPal Sandbox transaction in android

Tags: android, paypal-sandbox

I am developing an android application that uses payPal service.It was working fine I was able to do transaction in sandbox environment but recently I have been getting error while doing transactions

[Here is the screenshot please help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtS32.jpg)

please help i have attached screenshot

Comment: This may be Paypal Server issue , It happens some times while working with Paypal , If it was working fine for you previously then you can wait for this fix from Paypal end .

Comment: It has been showing this problem since last 3 days. Are you certain that there's a problem in the server ?

Comment: You have not mentioned in the question that it was not working since last 3 days , Let me digging more .

Comment: its problem in paypal server.i have faced that same issue.